# VBA - Different .address when assigning a range object with "Set" and "="

Tags: excel, vba, range, operators

I have this bit of code and I don´t understand this particular behavior:

1.
If I assign the range to rngSearch via 'Set' Keyword, than debug.print displays the result I expect: $P$1:$AI$1

2.
If I assign the range to rngSearch via '=' operator (and comment out 1.), than debug.print displays: $P$1

Since in both I alwas refer to the same range .Range(.Cells(1, lnFirstCol), .Cells(1, lnLastCol)) I don´t understand how in 2. he doesn´t take it.
I assume that he ignores the assignment and sticks with the first assignment.
Can you please explain why it happens?
Thank you!

```
Sub CreateFile()

Dim NewBook         As Workbook
Dim SheetToCopy     As String

SheetToCopy = "MasterVBATest"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetToCopy).Copy After:=Worksheets("Cockpit")
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim lnFirstCol As Long
Dim lnLastCol As Long
Dim ValueToFind As Variant

ValueToFind = "Trenner"

With ActiveSheet

    lnLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'First assignment
    Set rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lnLastCol)).Find(What:=ValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    Debug.Print rngSearch.Address 'Result: $P$1 --> expected
    If rngSearch Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print ValueToFind & " was not found."
    Else
        lnFirstCol = rngSearch.Column
    End If
     
    '1.
    'Set rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, lnFirstCol), .Cells(1, lnLastCol))
    'Debug.Print rngSearch.Address ' Result: $P$1:$AI$1 --> expected
    
    '2.
    rngSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, lnFirstCol), .Cells(1, lnLastCol))
    Debug.Print rngSearch.Address ' Result: $P$1

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand what `Find` does... It returns **one cell**, where/if a match in the range has been found... `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lnLastCol))` is the range where to search and the `Find` function returns something different.

Comment: Your #2 code tries to assign the **value** of the specified range to the `rngSearch` range (which was previously set to P1) so all you are doing is putting a value in P1.

Comment: @Rory: Thank you, I didn´t know that writing: someRange = someOtherRange is equivalent to someRange.Value = someOtherRange.Value  I thought that since rngSearch is a Range Object and .Range(.Cells(1, lnFirstCol), .Cells(1, lnLastCol)) is returning a Range Object too ( $P$1:$AI$1) I could assign this range object to the rngSearch Range Object as I do in 1.  I think the point is that to change the referenced object the only way is by using the Set Keyword

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, may clear your confusion..

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lnLastCol).find(something))

.Range(A1, Result P1) 'So you are getting combined range which is $P$1:$AI$1

.Cells(1, lnLastCol).find(something) 'This will give you P1
```